# gnuplot: tics at min and max value of colorbox

Tags: gnuplot

is there a way to format a colorbox so that the real range of the data is used and the max and min tic is the max/min value of the data?

For example, when I use this data file:

```
0 0 0.12
0 1 0.23
1 1 0.34
1 0 0.43
```

The command `plot 'data.dat' using 1:2:3 with points ps 1 pt 7 palette notitle` creates the following plot:
[image: Gnuplot 1]

To use the min/max of the data the cbrange is set to `[STATS_min:STATS_max]`:

```
stats 'data.dat' using 3
set cbrange [STATS_min:STATS_max]
plot 'data.dat' using 1:2:3 with points ps 1 pt 7 palette notitle
```

This creates the following plot:
[image: Gnuplot 2]

Is there a way to add a tic at `0.43` and at `0.12`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `set cbtics add` should work:

```
stats 'data.dat' using 3
set cbrange [STATS_min:STATS_max]
set cbtics add (STATS_min, STATS_max)
plot 'data.dat' using 1:2:3 with points ps 1 pt 7 palette notitle
```

This is the result:

[image: cbtics added]

You will find more information on setting tics with `help xtics`.